# Loading array value into another array value

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I'm trying to do an insertion sort in MIPS MARS 4.5.

I'm having some troubles specifically with:

A:

```
lw  myArray($s4), myArray($s6)# alist[position] = alist[position-1]
```

B:

```
lw  myArray($s4), $s5   # alist[position] = current value
```

The issue I'm getting is that "too many or incorrectly formated operands", and "myArray operand is of incorrect type", respectively.

Basically what i'm trying to do with exhibit A is mentioned in the comment, I'm trying to make myArray($s4) = myArray($s6), but it won't let me lw/la and i've also tried add to move it in.

For Exhibit B I want to change the value in myArray($s4) to be the value in $s5

Anyone able to help me out with the operator I should be using here?
Thanks

I've linked the rest of the function below in case that was needed.

Thanks again.

```
sort:
    addi    $sp, $sp, -32       # save values on stack
    sw  $ra, 0($sp)     # Store the saved values on the stack to restore when done
    sw  $s0, 4($sp)     # s0 = base address of array
    sw  $s1, 8($sp)     # s1 = size of array
    sw  $s2, 12($sp)        # s2 = i
    sw  $s3, 16($sp)        # s3 = j
    sw  $s4, 20($sp)        # s4 = position
    sw  $s5, 24($sp)        # s5 = currentvalue
    sw  $s6, 28($sp)        # s6 = position - 1

    la  $a0, myArray        # load array address into a0
    la  $a1, myArray($s2)   # load size of array into a1
    move    $s0, $a0        # move array address into s0
    move    $s1, $a1        # move size of array into s1
    li  $s2, 0          # set i to 0
    li  $s3, 0          # set j to 0
    li  $t0, 0          # set t0 to 0
 iloop:
 # if s1 >= size of array go to end
    slt $t5, $s2, $s1       # check if a1 > s2
    beq $t5, 0, endWhile    # if it is, jump to the end

    lw  $s5, myArray($s2)   # currentvalue = alist[i]
    add $s4, $zero, $s2     # position = i
    sub $s6, $s4, 4     # position - 1
    j   jloop           # else go to jloop
 jloop:
 # if position is <= 0
    slt $t5, $s4, $t0       # check if s4 is greater than 0
    beq $t5, 0, iloop       # if its less, jump to the end                
 # and alist[position-1] < currentvalue
    slt $t5, $s6, $s5       # check if alist[position-1] > current value
    beq $t5, 0, iloop       # if less than jump back to iloop
    lw  myArray($s4), myArray($s6)# alist[position] = alist[position-1]
    sub $s4, $s4, 1     # position = position - 1
    j   setArray
 setArray:
    lw  myArray($s4), $s5   # alist[position] = current value
    j   iloop
 endWhile:
```

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer: I never did MIPS assembler, so I'm just following the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set#MIPS_assembly_language) with my other assembly knowledge, thus I'm extremely vulnerable to do some stupid mistake or syntax error, let me know if it doesn't work)

`lw  myArray($s4), myArray($s6)` - you can't access the memory on both sides of "load/store" (move). That's too much on the CPU, only 1 side can be memory access, other must be register

```
lw $t5,myArray($s6) # $t5 set to alist[position-1]
sw $t5,myArray($s4) # alist[position] set to $t5
```

`lw  myArray($s4), $s5` - this is written as "load value v into memory", that's in human logic the same as "store value v into memory", but MIPS has only the second way: `sw $s5,myArray($s4)`.

---

Additional notes:
Why do you clutter all the `$s#` registers instead of using temporary `$t#`? You don't have to store/restore value of `$t#` regs, so it would probably save you from that long init (and long exit, if you would include it in question).

Use probably `$zero` instead of `0`. (unless the assembler is clever enough to change your `li $s2,0` into `add $s2,$zero,$zero`. If the MIPS is anywhere near to other old CPU designs, this should be "better way", than having zero as immediate (although any modern built MIPS CPU probably wouldn't make any difference between the two).

Why `myArray` hard-coded in? Can't you make this an procedure, taking array pointer and it's size as arguments from `$a0, $a1`?

`slt $t5, $s2, $s1       # check if a1 > s2` - don't do this, please. I mean the comment. If you will read this a year later, you will find that comment ridiculous (= correct, obvious and useless).

Try `# check if size (a1) > i (s2)`, which is tad better, but it flips the logic of `slt`. So `# set t5 if i (s2) < array size (s1)` is my final suggestion (notice how I also got rid of `a1`, as you don't use it any more).

edit:
On the problematic line `lw  myArray($s4), myArray($s6)# alist[position] = alist[position-1]` you did it right, you don't comment what the instruction does (which is obvious for anybody who knows the MIPS ASM), but you comment what was your human intent to achieve by that instruction. Keep it up like this one. But you may find out it gets difficult to comment every line in this way, as some lines groups naturally (like that `slt` + `beq`), then comment your intent by single line ahead of the group of instructions.

You can actually use that to write your algorithm first in few simple steps without any ASM instructions, or committing to usage of certain register, just pure comments. Then decide on register usage (for main values). And then fill up each comment with particular instructions achieving it. Usually helps to be not overwhelmed in your head by too many details while trying to do all algorithm, syntax, and register allocation at the same time.